# How many "social accounts" icons can be shown on your Github bio?

Tags: github, hyperlink, profile

### Context

So, GitHub recently update the bio to have up to four social account links.

[GitHub Social Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3bQg.jpg)

I tested many accounts, but only a couple of ones had an icon with it. 
The rest, had the normal "chain icon" for links.

### Question

So my question is: Has someone discovered how many links had an icon with it on GitHub social account links on bios? 
Is there an post on GitHub Docs abou it?

Thanks in advance.

### What have I tried

I got to GitHub Docs, but didn't found anything about it.

Also tried to search about it in other sources on the internet, same thing, no founds.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the [GitHub community forums](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions?discussions_q=is%3Aopen+profile+social+accounts), where there's a good chance you'd get an answer from a GitHub employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment (2023-05-06), the following 9 social accounts seem to be supported.

- twitter
- facebook
- instagram
- linkedin
- reddit
- twitch
- youtube
- mastodon
- hometown

The information above was taken from the HTML source of the settings page.

I couldn't find the place mentioned in GitHub Docs.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Answer (score 0):

The currently supported networks are 8 traditional social networks:

1. Facebook
2. Instagram
3. LinkedIn
4. npm *(missing from accepted answer)*
5. Reddit
6. Twitch
7. X *(formerly Twitter)*
8. YouTube

Plus, 2 decentralised networks:

1. Mastodon
2. Hometown *(Mastodon fork)*

Whilst this information isn't documented anywhere on GitHub besides [hints in release notes](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-02-add-more-social-links-to-your-user-profile/), you can find it yourself by viewing the source code of your GitHub profile and searching for `data-provider-key`. There will be duplicates (and the default `generic`), but all 10 will be there!

I also [wrote a short script](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/github-profile-supported-social-links/#checking-for-yourself) to extract all networks & regexes, but the information is all in the HTML.

*Disclaimer: My article, but no ads / monetisation.*